# Finding T* with an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a Inner product space V with a certain inner product, and a linear operator T above V, how do I find T* using the inner product? And what is the connection between T* and the space's inner product?

edit: How do I find the orthonormal vectors and what do I do with them after I find them?

Comment: Use the definition: $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle$ for $x,y\in V$.

Comment: And how do I find T* with that info?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have that the adjoint operator of an operator $\;T\;$ in an inner product vector space is the *unique* operator $\;T^*\;$ s.t.

$$\forall\;x,y\in V\;,\;\;\langle Tx\,,\,y\rangle=\langle x\,,\,T^*y\rangle\;\;\;\;\;(**)$$

Now, using an *orthonormal* basis and matrices one can save lots of time and mess, since then we have that $\;T^*=\overline{T^t}\;$ ...

Otherwise, you'll have to do the explicit calculations shown above in (**) for each specific case...

**Added on request:** we have for

$$\;A,B\in V:=M_n(\Bbb C)\;\;:\;\;\;\langle A,B\rangle:=tr.(B^*A)$$

and we have an operator

$$\;T:V\to V\;,\;\;TX:= A^{-1}XA\;,\;\;\text{for a constant, fixed}\;A\in V\;$$

(look at this carefully: what you wrote in the comments above is *not* a linear operator. The above one **is**).

If you work **all through** with an orthonormal basis of $\;V\;$ , which you can work out with the Gram-Schmidt method on any given basis, and then you express your operator $\;T\;$ wrt that orthonormal basis, then you have that

$$T^*X=(A^*)^{-1}XA^*\;,\;\;\;\text{with}\;\;A=\overline{A^t}$$

As simple as that. Otherwise, you'll have to work with some given $\;A\;$ which may or may not be the matrix representation of $\;T\;$ wrt an orthonormal basis, but the $\;T^*\;$ may not have such an easy representation as the above...

You may want to work out some examples with $\;n=2\;$ , say. This is the way one gets practice and insight into all these things.

Comment: I don't really get it, how do I use it? and what do I do with the basis? Do I need it to find T*?

Comment: How do you use **what** ? If you're given an **explicit** example then you need to do the *actual* calculations to find out what $\;T^*\;$ is. If you're given an orthonormal basis to work with then you can save some time and effort as shown above...I doubt much more than this can be said in the general case.

Comment: What do I in a case like T(X) = (X^(-1))*A*X?

Comment: What are $\;X,A\;$ in your comment??

Comment: Matrices that I don't know anything about them besides that A is invertable

Comment: Wonderful: then on what inner product space are you working and what's the inner product there?! You can't write questions just like that without making *a little effort* to make them **clear** !

Comment: Lets say that the vector space is V=C^(n*n) and the inner product is <A,B> = tr((B*)*A). (a question from a test), Now how do I find T*?

Comment: Well, why did you **not** begin with that, for Gauss's sake?? You should add this to your original question and perhaps later I will add something to my answer...but the answer's already *there*, anyway!

Comment: So can you edit it please? and I didn't do that because I was afraid that I wouldn't get an answer because It would look like I was trying to cheat. Can you add the solution to this example to your answer? or at least tell me how can I solve it myself?

Comment: Done, @Catamorpihsm

Comment: Why isn't T* = A*X*(A*^(-1))? @DonAntonio

Comment: You can orthonormalize **any** basis and work with it thereafter. Google "Gram-Schmidt"

Comment: And after I have that basis orthonormalized,  how do I continue trying to find T*?